# Deobfuscate PHP that contains - goto

Tags: deobfuscation, php

I've found a bunch of obfuscated PHP scripts in my server but it seems I cannot deobfuscate them to follow the code flow. I came to the conclusion that the files have been obfuscated with https://www.php-obfuscator.com/ and no deobfuscate tool that I know can convert php goto/labels to loops so I strongly think this is not a duplicate question. Can goto/labels be converted to while/foreach loops?

Comment: Paste/link some of the scripts for people to try out.

Comment: I have provided some code to help the user that asked which was deleted without any notice. Why?

Comment: @Arch hop into the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=reverseengineering.stackexchange.com) and I'll explain.